# Cannot install tensorflow in windows

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

`F:\my projects\Python codes>pip install tensorflow`

`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow`

I have tried this even in the cmd and i use python 3.8.2 and dosent have anaconda and i run my code in microsoft visual studio please help he solve this problem.

Thank You.

Comment: Most probably you have installed the 32bit Python. Go to www.python.org/downloads, download the x86-64 installer and reinstall Python.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this please upgade your pip since `tensorflow 2.0` can not be installed on some earlier version of `pip`. For more information check https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip.

Comment: i have tried it this is not working if i try to install it says the same error

Comment: i check but there isn't any answer

Comment: @Yagav Please add you computer / Python specifications to the question